# How can I manually enable or disable the Return Key on the keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard

I have a `UITextView` that receives input from the keyboard. The "Auto Enable Return Key" checkbox is checked, so when the `UITextView` is empty the Return key is disabled.

I have an Emoticons bar above the keyboard that can add emoticons to the `UITextView` as well, but here's the problem; When the `UITextView` is empty and I add an emoticon to the `UITextView` like this:

```
[inputTextView insertText:@"\ue40d"];
```

then the ReturnKey is still disabled, although the UITextView's text property is not empty.

I've tried this after inserting an emoticon:

```
[inputTextView setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
```

With no results. It looks like enabling/disabling the Return Key of the keyboard is only triggered by entering characters through the keyboard.

Any idea's how to do manually enable/disable the Return key?

Comment: Does it work as intended if you type normal text into it?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could try inserting the text via the pasteboard instead:

```
UIPasteboard* generalPasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

// Save a copy of the system pasteboard's items
// so we can restore them later.
NSArray* items = [generalPasteboard.items copy];

// Set the contents of the system pasteboard
// to the text we wish to insert.
generalPasteboard.string = text;

// Tell this responder to paste the contents of the
// system pasteboard at the current cursor location.
[textfield paste: nil];

// Restore the system pasteboard to its original items.
generalPasteboard.items = items;

// Free the items array we copied earlier.
[items release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
textField.setValue(isEnabled, forKeyPath: "inputDelegate.returnKeyEnabled")
```

Fox example inside

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Answer (score -1):

uncheck "Auto Enable Return Key"